# Survival function in nonparametric models

Tags: survival

Usually, in survival analysis, we interpret survival

$S(t) = P(T > t)$

but I came across the definition
$S(t) = P(T >= t)$
in the context of nonparametric methods (lifetable and kaplan-meier).

In case of nonparametric methods, we should interpret survival as probability of event occurence after t or exactly in time t ?

Comment: What is the chance of occurrence *precisely* at time $t$?  That quantifies the difference between the two definitions.

Comment: In life-table method I guess probability P(T=t) is not defined, because we have intervals => Probability of event in interval under condition that event didnt occur until start of the interval : P(T >20, T<30 | T >= 20)

Comment: Since in these applications $\{t\}$ is a measurable set, its probability *must* be defined.  It is zero.

Comment: sorry, I dont understand. My question is whether S(t) = P(T>=t) or P(T>t) in life table method. What is the influence of the fact that P(T=t)=0 on definition of S(t) ?

Comment: Because $\Pr(T \ge t) = \Pr(T=t) + \Pr(T \gt t).$

Comment: so in life-table method S(T>=t) = S(T>t) ?

Comment: If survival for interval <20,30) is 0,9, then we conclude that probability of event after 20 day is 90% ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem is not strictly related to the use of nonparametric methods but to the formal definition of $S(t)$. Regardless of the estimation method, in the continuous case there is an equivalence between $P(T\geq t)$ and $P(T>t)$, and the two can be used interchangeably.

The problem in choosing one definition versus the other only occurs in the discrete case where the two are not the same (because $P(T=t)\neq 0$). In this situation you generally encounter the definition $P(T\geq t)$ when proving the relationships between $\lambda(t), f(t), S(t)$. Specifically,

\begin{eqnarray*}
\lambda(t) \Delta t  & \approx &   P(t \le T <
t+\Delta t | T \ge t) & = &
 \frac{P(t
\le T <  t+\Delta t)}{P(T \ge t)} & = & \frac{f(t) \Delta t}{S(t)}
\end{eqnarray*}

That is, in the discrete case this relationship is only valid if we define $S(t)=P(T\geq t)$

In practical terms, given that the survival curve in the discrete case is a step function, the interpretation is the same with the caveat that on the time points where we have the jumps we are assuming that the function is right continuous.